# C input loop for shell

Tags: c, shell, loops, input

So I'm working on creating a very simple C program that just preforms shell commands. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char input[30];
fputs("$ ", stdout);
fflush(stdout);
fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
system(input);
}
```

It works, but only for one command. For example if I compile and type ./cmd I get the $ prompt. If I type ls I get what I'm supposed to get. But then it exits and goes back to the regular system shell. How can I make it so after the user types a command it goes back to the "$" input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are *loops*; if you want to have the exit condition determined by the user input, actually you probably need to have an infinite loop (the idiomatic way is `for(;;)`) and an `if` after the input acquisition that results in a `break` if your condition is satisfied.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input[30];
    for(;;) /* infinite loop */
    {
        fputs("$ ", stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
        if(/* put here your exit condition */)
            break; /* breaks out of the loop */
        system(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your exit condition will probably involve using `strcmp` (from `<string.h>`) to perform the comparison between the string entered by the user and your exit command.

Comment: Thanks works pretty well actually. What would i put in the exit condition to make the shell exit if the user types "exit"?

Comment: It was left as an exercise to the reader, but since all other answers already stated it... it should be `strcmp(input, "exit\n")==0`; have a look at the `strcmp` documentation to understand how this works.

Comment: I would argue that the idiomatic way for this is a do-while loop.

Comment: @SiegeX: No, because the condition is almost surely in the *middle* of the loop body, not at the end. This is why do-while is rarely useful... :-(

Comment: @SiegeX: some people use `while(1)` for infinite loops, but this may trigger warnings in several compilers when you have a high warning level ("constant expression in conditional"), so `for(;;)` is usually preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your code inside a loop. For example:

```
int main()
{
    while (1) {
        char input[30];
        fputs("$ ", stdout);    
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
        system(input);
    }
}
```

The `while (1) { ... }` is an infinite loop. The only way to exit this would be to kill your program in some way. To be able to exit the loop with a command, you'll need to put some kind of condition inside it:

```
    while (1) {
        char input[30];
        fputs("$ ", stdout);    
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
        if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        system(input);
    }
```

The `strcmp()` does a compare to see if you typed "exit". If so, then the `break` statement exits the nearest loop, and your program ends.

Comment: Fixed that. You must be using a pretty old C.

Comment: @AustinM: in C89 `bool`, `true` and `false` aren't defined (and in C99 too if you don't include `stdbool.h`); put `1` instead of `true` or use `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want just any loop, you want a `do while` loop because you always want to perform the `system()` command at least once.  Also, by having the keyword `exit` be your break condition, there is no need for extra code to check `input` before you call `system()` because `exit` will kill both your shell and your program if you use `strcmp()` as the do-while conditional statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char input[30];
  do {
    fputs("$ ", stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
    system(input);
  } while(strcmp(input,"exit\n"));

  return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
[siegex@localhost]$ ./myshell
$ echo foo
foo
$ echo bar | sed 's/r/z/'
baz
$ exit
[siegex@localhost]$
```